# Java "Fire and Forget" Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, fire-and-forget

I have a method

```
public static void startAnimation() {
    new AnimationThread().run();
}
```

where AnimationThread implements runnable and its constructor is:

```
public AnimationThread() {
    new Thread(this, "Animation Thread");
    EventQueue.setAnimationCounter(0);
    alive = true;
}
```

which i am calling from the init() method of an applet hangs as it never returns a value. Is there a way to start this thread and get the init() method to finish so that my applet will start!

Thanks

Comment: You need to start() a thread. Calling `run()` is like any other method, it runs in the current threads and only returns when it completes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to move things around a bit:

```
public AnimationThread() {
   EventQueue.setAnimationCounter(0);
   alive = true;
   new Thread(this, "Animation Thread").start();
}

public static void startAnimation() {
   new AnimationThread();
}
```

`start()` is the magic `Thread` method that runs code on a different thread; the `AnimationThread` constructor will return normally after calling it, the `AnimationThread.run()` will execute in a new thread.

Comment: Note that it might be problematic under certain circumstances to start a new thread in a constructor (see [findbugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#SC_START_IN_CTOR) for details on this). A simple way to prevent this is making the AnimationThread-class final.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should call the `start` method instead the `run` method. Only `start` method really executes a new thread.

Comment: Indeed, although `AnimationThread` doesn't have a `start()` method, despite its name.